# ruby tags for Sphinx/rst

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, ruby-characters

I create HTML documents from a rst-formated text, with the help of [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html). I need to display some Japanese words with [furiganas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana) (=small characters above the words), something like that :
[image: Japanese text with furiganas over some words]

I'd like to produce HTML displaying furiganas thanks to [the < ruby > tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ruby.asp).

I can't figure out how to get this result. I tried to:

- insert raw HTML code with the [.. raw:: html directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) but it breaks my line into several paragraphs.
- use the [:superscript: directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#subscript) but the text in furigana is written *beside* the text, not *above*.
- use the [:role: directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#custom-interpreted-text-roles) to create a link between the text and a CSS class of my own. But the :role: directive can only be applied to a segment of text, not to TWO segments as required by the furiganas (=text + text above it).

Any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I know, there's no simple way to get the expected result.

[For a specific project](https://github.com/suizokukan/logotheras), I choosed not to generate the furiganas with the help of Sphinx but to modify the .html files afterwards. See the `add_ons/add_furiganas.py` script and the result [here](http://94.23.197.37/hologenri). Yes, it's a quick-and-dirty trick :(